# Bootstrap popover not working on second click

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32009037/4746087) question, my popover is not shown on the second, fourth, sixth ... click, while I'm trying to fade it out. My code:

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
    placement: 'bottom',
    delay: {
        show: 50
    }
});

$('[data-toggle="popover"]').click(function () {

    setTimeout(function () {
        $('.popover').fadeOut('slow');
    }, 1000);
});
```

The answer provided in the link, claims it is a Bootstrap 3.3.5 bug. Although, I'm working with bootstrap 3.3.7, the proposed solution does not do the trick:

```
if ($.fn.popover.Constructor.VERSION == "3.3.7") {
     $('[data-toggle="popover"]').on("hidden.bs.popover", function() {
          $(this).data("bs.popover").inState.click = false
     })
}
```

To see the bug in action: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/20crkufk/11/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems the bug isn't fixed yet in 3.3.7, but the proposed solution actually works. You still need to hide the popover with `.popover('hide')`, instead of just fading out. The following will do the trick:

```
$('.popover').fadeOut('slow').popover('hide');
```

Use this in combination with:

```
if ($.fn.popover.Constructor.VERSION == "3.3.7") {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').on("hidden.bs.popover", function() {
        $(this).data("bs.popover").inState.click = false
    })
}
```